# Proving that swapping the order of this summation is justified

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-explanation, polylogarithm

I'm unsure if this has been discovered already, but it's heavily related to my current research, particularly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996559/194117) of mine (this conjecture was also originally posted at the beginning of my [most recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011035/194117)). My conjecture is the following:

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous on the open interval $a\lt x\lt b$. If $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$, then  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b\mathrm{Li}_k(f(x))\,dx=-\int_a^bf(x)\ln(1-f(x))\,dx,\tag{*}$$ where $\mathrm{Li}_k(z)$ represents the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) of order $k$.

I've made an assumption along the way during my proof, and I need help in showing that it's justified.

> We start with the series definition for polylogarithms to obtain $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b\mathrm{Li}_k(f(x))\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n^k}dx.\tag{1}$$ Since we are given the initial condition $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$, the value of the series at $n=1$ is also $0$. Therefore, we have $$\begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b\mathrm{Li}_k(f(x))\,dx&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n^k}dx}\tag{2}\\&=\color{red}{\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n^k}dx}.\tag{3}\\
> \end{align}$$
>   Noting that the inner sum is a geometric series, we get $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n^k}dx=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n-1}dx.\tag{4}$$ Finally, using the Mercator series gives us $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_a^b\frac{(f(x))^n}{n-1}dx=-\int_a^b f(x)\ln(1-f(x))\,dx,\tag{5}$$ as desired.

Between equations 2 and 3, I assumed that swapping the order of summation was justified. However, this would require showing that the series converges for *all* $f(x)$ satisfying the initial conditions (see [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/twosum.pdf)). The conjecture holds for $f(x)=\ln{x}$ with $0\lt x\lt e$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996559/194117)), $f(x)=\cos{x}$ for $0\lt x\lt \pi$, and appears to hold numerically for $f(x)=\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2+1}$ for $0\lt x\lt \infty$. This leads to another problem: the series definition for $\mathrm{Li}_s(z)$ only holds for $|z|\lt1$. However, for some reason, this conjecture appears to avoid that restriction entirely. It also appears to hold even if $f(x)\gt1$, but the resulting value would be complex. Needless to say, I'm completely lost.

Comment: Notice that analytic continuation can come into play

Comment: If $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)$$ then we need to prove $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n,k)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\lim_{K\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Kf(n,k)=\lim_{K\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Kf(n,k)$$ where we have double limit?  Show taking limit with $K$ first or $N$ first that it comes out the same.

Comment: @SimpleArt I haven't taken a formal course in real analysis, so I'm a bit confused. The equivalence holds trivially if $|f(x)|\leq1$ is true for $a\lt x\lt b$, but otherwise my approach seems invalid. Do I need to scrap the proof entirely and use another method?

Comment: No no, I mean that to have two infinite sums, you consider the partial sums, by definition, then rearrange.  And as long as you derive an analytic solution for a dense set of values, by analytic continuation, it will hold everywhere the solution exists.

Comment: [Analytic continuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) is a powerful tool.

Comment: @SimpleArt So proving that both of the partial sums converge would be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, because switching the finite sums are allowed.